# MSI GTX 1080 Ti with Ubuntu 16.1

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am trying to install Ubunt 16.1 on my PC (`MSI GTX 1080 Ti`, Motherboard: `ASUS Z170-P`). I used the `Nvidia 381` driver by `apt-get`. Additionally I tried other versions of Ubuntu (16.04.1, 14.04.5), another version of the Nvidia driver (`378.13`). In all cases it behaves the same, immediately after login it automatically logs out. Also I tried this the steps from this guide [NVidia GTX 1080 installation on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](http://abhay.harpale.net/blog/linux/nvidia-gtx-1080-installation-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts/) with no change. How to see what exactly happens internally and how to fix?